# The "in" D Storage Class

Tags: parameters, d

When using the `in` storage class in D the data is immutable to your function. Does this also pass in the data by reference and not by value? I noticed that `in ref` is not valid.

If `in` doesn't pass in the data by reference, is there a way to get the data by reference but have a guarantee to the caller that the data will not be modified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`in` parameters are [not passed by reference](http://ideone.com/c7FiT).

As far as I can tell from [the documentation](http://dlang.org/function.html#parameters), `in` is just a shortcut for `const scope`.  I do not see any way to emulate `ref in` parameters, since `ref scope` is illegal.  As BCS said, you can use `ref const` if you don't care about the `scope` storage class.

Comment: By the way: how better is to pass "huge" class object to function? in C++ const references are used - so, `ref const BaseClass obj` is completely similar to `const BaseClass& obj` in C++?

Comment: @Raxillan Yes, they are equivalent.  It's also worth noting that `ref` is only necessary for huge structs, as classes are always passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks! However, it's strange for me what structs and classes are different entities in D - in C++ `struct` is just a class with default `public` protection to all it members. Interesting.

Comment: @Raxillan That was the idea. If you think about it, C++ is the strange one. Why should two completely different computer science concepts be implemented identically save for a trivial tweak? D structs are user defined data *struct*ures, while classes are user defined objects (in the java/smalltalk/most other languages sense).

Comment: So, this is difference: user-defined _data_ and _objects_. Thanks, now it's clear for me.

Comment: @Tim - Structures are value-types, while classes are reference-types. Saying that "*classes are user defined objects*" is wrong because object is an instance of a class (in object-oriented programming).

Comment: @DejanLekic Yes, my mistake. I should have said instances of classes are user defined objects, the classes themselves are maybe more properly user defined interfaces for objects, or perhaps class is one of those fundamental, irreducible terms for the field of OOP. In any case, my point was that the two concepts (data structures vs. objects) are distinct. Fair?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked but I believe `ref const` should work.

Comment: That compiles, but if `in` doesn't pass by reference (does it?) then what's the point of haivng `in`?

Comment: @BobD, I'm not sure what is to happen with 'in,' but its inception was to allow the compiler to optimize how it saw fit. This meant that it could pass by reference if desired. I do not think it ever does and don't know the plans for it.